# R - How to echo code, evaluation of code with variable values and result?

Tags: r

```
# This simple function illustrates my request
simple <- function(base, power) {
  base^power
}

simple(2,4)
# Returns 
# [1] 16
#
# What I would like to see is something like this: 
# 1) Code
# 2) Code replaced by values
# 3) Returned value 
#
# base^power
# 2^4
# [1] 16
#
```

What option(s) would allow me to see this type of information?

Adding more background on this question, I am seeking a way for the R system to consistently return this type of information on demand for archival and auditing purposes (like in pharma, banking, etc.)  I appreciate all the effort for writing code specifically for this purpose, but I am seeking the clean code with a system option for this behavior (like this in SAS:
options mput mlogic symbolgen;)

Comment: I don't think you can, but how about you explain why you want this, maybe you're approaching the problem from the wrong end.

Comment: I am seeking something akin to this in SAS:
    options mprint mlogic symbolgen;  This allows you to see the full evaluation logic in detail, very useful in audited industries like pharma, banking, etc.

Comment: I started writing down something using 'substitute' and 'bquote', but then I had to stop. You might take a look at: http://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2001-3.pdf Which has some hints on writing macros, which is along the lines of what you want to do. As is pointed out below, you can probably do some of it with text substitution, but that is less elegant than using macro-like facilty.

Answer (score 3):

This won't work for default values or `...` or if variables are out of order (or I'm sure a bunch of other edge cases), but should at least give you a starting point:

```
show.fn = function(fn, ...) {
  # #1
  print(fn)

  # #2
  vals = list(...)
  args = names(as.list(args(fn)))
  fn.txt = c(capture.output(print(fn)), "\n")

  for (i in seq_along(vals)) {
    fn.txt = gsub(args[i], vals[i], fn.txt)
  }

  cat(paste(fn.txt, collapse = "\n"))

  # #3
  print(fn(...))
}

show.fn(simple, 2, 4)
#function(base, power) {
#  base^power
#}
#function(2, 4) {
#  2^4
#}
#
#[1] 16
```

The above does a simple text substitution; if you want a real walk through the code, you can do `debug(simple)` and then step through and print out whatever variables.

Answer (score 0):

Hadley Wickham was kind enough to reply directly, 
"You can have a look at pryr::unenclose, for one approach, but in
general it's going to be hard to do in general, and fragile."

I am hoping there is some secret alternative lurking in the ether, but this isn't looking very promising after seeing his reply.

For a writeup of the desired options illustrated in SAS, see http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/128-29.pdf